# Can't use Liquibase with the MongoDB Pro Extension

Tags: mongodb, liquibase

When I use "liquibase update" command I get an error like below
[image]

I put my liquibase project in the following git repo

https://github.com/aayoubb/LiquibaseTest/tree/main/liquibase

and I added liquibase-commercial-mongodb jar to liquibase/lib directory to be able to use mongosh
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase.ext/liquibase-commercial-mongodb/1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with the version 4.23.0 of liquibase according to this post https://forum.liquibase.org/t/liquibase-mongodb-extension-issue/8403/2
so the solution will be to use the 4.21.0 liquibase version or wait for a fix